# Import structured XML file to SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, openrowset

I'm trying to download and import a XML file to an SQL Table.
The download is working perfectly and it generates the following XML file.

### GeoPers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtcResponse xmlns="http://www.geodynamics.be/webservices">
        <Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtcResult>
            <ClockingEntity>
                <Id>af261a77-a35b-4778-a175-6fd50d00cde1</Id>
                <DateTimeUtc>2017-09-28T02:37:56Z</DateTimeUtc>
                <DateTimeLocal>2017-09-28T04:37:56</DateTimeLocal>
                <User>
                    <Id>4975535a-2690-4492-bc7f-5e8a7d839cb9</Id>
                    <Name>Marcel De Doncker</Name>
                    <DayProgramId xsi:nil="true"/>
                </User>
                <Vehicle>
                    <Id>52e01d9c-96fa-46ed-98fe-f62e1792f019</Id>
                    <Code>7080</Code>
                    <Name>Auto: Dacia Dokker 1-PAE-120</Name>
                    <VehicleTypeId xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <LastSyncDateUtc xsi:nil="true"/>
                </Vehicle>
                <Type>StartMovementDriver</Type>
                <Location>
                <Address>
                    <Street>Kapelleveld</Street>
                    <HouseNumber>49</HouseNumber>
                    <PostalCode>1785</PostalCode>
                    <City>Merchtem</City>
                    <Submunicipality>Merchtem</Submunicipality>
                    <Country>Belgium</Country>
                </Address>
                <Longitude>4.2380828857421875</Longitude>
                <Latitude>50.9540901184082</Latitude>
                </Location>
                <Pois/>
                <IsManual>false</IsManual>
            </ClockingEntity>
        </Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtcResult>
    </Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtcResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm using the following query to load the file into SQL:

### SQL QUERY

```
DECLARE @XmlFile XML

SELECT @XmlFile = BulkColumn  
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Temp\GeoDynamics\Downloads\GeoPers.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x

SELECT 
    Id = resource.value('(Id)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    DateTimeUtc = resource.value('(DateTimeUtc)[2]', 'varchar(255)'),
    DateTimeLocal = resource.value('(DateTimeLocal)[3]', 'varchar(255)'),
    UserID = resource.value('(User/Id)[4]', 'varchar(255)'),
    UserName = resource.value('(User/Name)[5]', 'varchar(255)'),
    VehicleID = resource.value('(Vehicle/Id)[6]', 'varchar(255)'),
    VehicleCode = resource.value('(Vehicle/Code)[7]', 'varchar(255)'),
    VehicleName = resource.value('(Vehicle/Name)[8]', 'varchar(255)')
 FROM
@XmlFile.nodes('//Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtcResponse/Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtcResult/ClockingEntity') AS XTbl1(resource)
```

The query gives no result, not even an error code. I don't know where I'm wrong in the query.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that your XML has a default namespace (`http://www.geodynamics.be/webservices`). You will need to use [the `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/with-xmlnamespaces) to specify that namespace for your query.

As mentioned in the other answer, you will also need to fix the indexes in your XPath queries - they should all be `[1]`.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.geodynamics.be/webservices')
SELECT 
    Id = resource.value('(Id)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    DateTimeUtc = resource.value('(DateTimeUtc)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    DateTimeLocal = resource.value('(DateTimeLocal)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    UserID = resource.value('(User/Id)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    UserName = resource.value('(User/Name)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    VehicleID = resource.value('(Vehicle/Id)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    VehicleCode = resource.value('(Vehicle/Code)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    VehicleName = resource.value('(Vehicle/Name)[1]', 'varchar(255)')
FROM
    @XmlFile.nodes('//Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtcResponse/Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtcResult/ClockingEntity') AS XTbl1(resource);
```

Output:

```
Id                af261a77-a35b-4778-a175-6fd50d00cde1
DateTimeUtc       2017-09-28T02:37:56Z
DateTimeLocal     2017-09-28T04:37:56
UserID            4975535a-2690-4492-bc7f-5e8a7d839cb9
UserName          Marcel De Doncker
VehicleID         52e01d9c-96fa-46ed-98fe-f62e1792f019
VehicleCode       7080
VehicleName       Auto: Dacia Dokker 1-PAE-120
```

[Add Namespaces to Queries with WITH XMLNAMESPACES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/add-namespaces-to-queries-with-with-xmlnamespaces)

Answer (score 1):

This will work. You are not selecting in the correct namespace; use [WITH XMLNAMESPACES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/with-xmlnamespaces) for this. Second, you are selecting with the wrong index apart from the `Id` element; the index `[n]` you specify will select the n-th occurance of the element. You always need to first one.

```sql
DECLARE @x XML=N'
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtcResponse xmlns="http://www.geodynamics.be/webservices">
        <Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtcResult>
            <ClockingEntity>
                <Id>af261a77-a35b-4778-a175-6fd50d00cde1</Id>
                <DateTimeUtc>2017-09-28T02:37:56Z</DateTimeUtc>
                <DateTimeLocal>2017-09-28T04:37:56</DateTimeLocal>
                <User>
                    <Id>4975535a-2690-4492-bc7f-5e8a7d839cb9</Id>
                    <Name>Marcel De Doncker</Name>
                    <DayProgramId xsi:nil="true"/>
                </User>
                <Vehicle>
                    <Id>52e01d9c-96fa-46ed-98fe-f62e1792f019</Id>
                    <Code>7080</Code>
                    <Name>Auto: Dacia Dokker 1-PAE-120</Name>
                    <VehicleTypeId xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <LastSyncDateUtc xsi:nil="true"/>
                </Vehicle>
                <Type>StartMovementDriver</Type>
                <Location>
                <Address>
                    <Street>Kapelleveld</Street>
                    <HouseNumber>49</HouseNumber>
                    <PostalCode>1785</PostalCode>
                    <City>Merchtem</City>
                    <Submunicipality>Merchtem</Submunicipality>
                    <Country>Belgium</Country>
                </Address>
                <Longitude>4.2380828857421875</Longitude>
                <Latitude>50.9540901184082</Latitude>
                </Location>
                <Pois/>
                <IsManual>false</IsManual>
            </ClockingEntity>
        </Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtcResult>
    </Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtcResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';
```

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.geodynamics.be/webservices' )
SELECT 
    Id = resource.value('(Id)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    DateTimeUtc = resource.value('(DateTimeUtc)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    DateTimeLocal = resource.value('(DateTimeLocal)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    UserID = resource.value('(User/Id)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    UserName = resource.value('(User/Name)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    VehicleID = resource.value('(Vehicle/Id)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    VehicleCode = resource.value('(Vehicle/Code)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    VehicleName = resource.value('(Vehicle/Name)[1]', 'varchar(255)')
 FROM
    @x.nodes('//Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtcResponse/Clocking_GetByDateRangeUtcResult/ClockingEntity') AS XTbl1(resource)
```